# Problems with region-related functions

Tags: plotting, regions

For a demonstration project, I am calculating certain geometric properties of a region (an isosceles triangle in this example), as follows:

```
baseshape = SASTriangle[2, Pi/6, 2];
cbs0 = RegionCentroid[baseshape];
baseshape = TransformedRegion[baseshape, TranslationTransform[-cbs0]];
```

This calculates the centroid, and moves the region so its centroid is at the origin. Now I am going to rotate the region, move it down by `depth`, and define the part of the region that lies below `y=0` as a new region, as follows:

```
rrs[\[Theta]_?NumericQ, depth_?NumericQ] := 
  RegionIntersection[
   TransformedRegion[
    TransformedRegion[baseshape, RotationTransform[\[Theta]]], 
    TranslationTransform[{0, -depth}]], 
   ImplicitRegion[y <= 0, {x, y}]];
```

However, I get an error message when I try to plot this:

```
Plot[Area[rrs[0, depth]], {depth, -0.7, 1.4}]

Area::reg: rrs(0,d,{0,0}) is not a correctly specified region.
```

The plot looks fine, but I don't understand the reason for the error message.
What am I missing?

Comment: Evaluating `Area[rrs[0,depth]]` gives a pure function with several variables, may be the reason behind the error message.

Comment: The standard trick is to define `area[depth_?NumericQ] := Area[rrs[0, depth]]` and plot `area[depth]`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error comes from the evaluation of `Area[rrs[0, depth]]` with the non-evaluated symbol `depth`:

```
Plot[Area[rrs[0, Echo@depth]], {depth, -0.6, -0.5}, 
     PlotPoints -> 2, MaxRecursion -> 1]

>> -0.6
>> -0.5999
>> depth
Area::reg: rrs[0,depth] is not a correctly specified region.
>> -0.6
>> -0.5
>> -0.55

(* plot displayed *)
```

This symbolic evaluation happens as part of the detection of exclusions. You can avoid it by setting the option `Exclusions` to `None`:

```
Plot[Area[rrs[0, Echo@depth]], {depth, -0.6, -0.5}, 
     PlotPoints -> 2, MaxRecursion -> 1, Exclusions -> None]

>> -0.6
>> -0.5999
>> -0.6
>> -0.5
>> -0.55

(* plot displayed *)
```

Note that `Plot` has the default value `Exclusions -> Automatic`, which is effectively equivalent to `Exclusions -> All` when the option `PerformanceGoal` is `Quality` (see `Exclusions` [ref page](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Exclusions.html)),

```
Options[Plot, "PerformanceGoal"]
(* {PerformanceGoal :> $PerformanceGoal} *)

$PerformanceGoal
(* "Quality" *)
```

so another way to get rid of the message is to set `PerformanceGoal` to another value:

```
Plot[Area[rrs[0, Echo@depth]], {depth, -0.6, -0.5}, 
     PlotPoints -> 2, MaxRecursion -> 1, PerformanceGoal -> "Speed"]

>> -0.6
>> -0.5999
>> -0.6
>> -0.5
>> -0.55

(* plot displayed *)
```

This last approach may be more interesting if you want to process excluded regions with `ExclusionsStyle` (in this case the value of `Exclusions` should not be `Automatic`, and needs to be set to another value --- for instance `True` or `All`).

Comment: Great answer, thanks! Now I understand why Plot attempts to evaluate expressions with non-numeric values.