# Why plotting a NIntegrate function gives errors in v11?

Tags: plotting, evaluation, version-11

Example code:

```
f[y_] := NIntegrate[x, {x, 0, y}]
Plot[f[y], {y, 0, 1}]
```

It works in v10.4, but in v11.0, even though *Mathematica* shows the plot, it also gives (the same) errors:

> NIntegrate:x=y is not a valid limit of integration.
>   NIntegrate:x=y is not a valid limit of integration.

The error is nonsense to me since `Plot` has attributes `HoldAll`, and I know I can suppress the errors by adding `?NumericQ` to the parameter `y`, however, the question is

WHY?

Comment: out of curiosity, what do you get evaluating `Trace[Plot[f[y], {y, 0, 1}], f]`? Or better yet, what evaluating `Trace[Plot[f[y], {y, 0, 1}], f, TraceInternal -> True]`? An evaluation of the form `f[y]` should explain why this happen (I don't see any in v10.4, and I do not experience this behaviour)

Comment: @glS The nontrival part is `NIntegrate[x, {x, 0, 0.0000204286}]`, both in v11 and 10.4

Comment: what if you try with the `TraceInternal` option?

Comment: @glS I think they are the same. The form is `f[val],NIntegrate[x,{x,0,val}]` where val is the points between 0 and 1.

Comment: As `Plot[f[Echo[y]], {y, 0.01, 1}]` shows, the function is evaluated symbolically at one point. As you already stated, one can prevent the symbolic evaluation by using `?NumericQ`. What precisely is your question? Why there is a symbolic evaluation or why it is different in v11 than in v10?

Comment: Specifically this answer: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/26037/12 and http://support.wolfram.com/kb/12502  The fact that it worked in 10.4 doesn't mean that doing it this way is correct. You *do* need `NumericQ` there. `Plot` uses heuristics to try to save you from this mistake but it's not foolproof.

Comment: @Szabolcs Thanks for the link, but I'm still confused after reading it. Since `Plot` hold its arguments, the seems no reason for `f[y]` to be pre-evaluated,  i.e. `y` will always be a numeric value, so it should be no warnings despite of its low efficiency.

Comment: @luyuwuli `HoldAll` means that the argument is passed into a function without evaluation, so the function can do whatever it wants with it.  That includes evaluating it.  Plot does evaluate it.  Example: `SetAttributes[fun, HoldAll]; fun[x_] := x`. When you call `fun[x]`, `x` gets evaluated at some point, just a little later than it would be without `HoldAll`.

Comment: @Szabolcs Ah. I understand it. Thanks! (What a silly mistake I've made.)

Comment: @luyuwuli `Plot` even has an undocumented `Evaluated` option which controls what sorts of evaluations it will attempts internally.  I don't fully understand its effect, and setting it to `False` doesn't fix things here ... Maybe something *is* wrong with v11.  One reason why `Plot` would evaluate the function with a symbolic argument is that it may do symbolic processing to determine the `Exclusions`.

Comment: @luyuwuli You may be interested in this [post](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/125835/problems-with-region-related-functions).

Comment: @Szabolcs Yes, I've also tried `Evaluated->False`, it dosen't prevent the error (even thougth I didn't post it in the question.) I thought it was the same as the `HoldAll` attributes. Your comment reminds me that indeed some non-trival part is modified in v11.